# Is Marginal Rate of Substitution a multivariable function?

Tags: microeconomics, consumer-theory

Suppose I have $U(x,y)$ and a level set of indifference curves. Suppose the value of $U$ along a given curve is $\bar{U}$. We know $dU = 0$. We compute total derivative, rearrange, and now have

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{U_x}{U_y}$$

**My Confusion and Question:**

$\frac{dy}{dx}$ is written as a function of a single variable right? But when we talk about $MU$, we always talk about it as a multivariable function. I thought $MRS$ was the ordinal utility analog of the cardinal utility $MU$. So why is $MRS$ a single variable function?

Answer (score 1):

> $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is written as a function of a single variable right?

I don't think so. Your shorthand notation should be standing for

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{U_x(x, y)}{U_y(x,y} $$

and hence is a function of both variables ${x,y}$. That makes sense, as your MRS could depend on the locus you're at.

Comment: Okay. I buy what you are saying about the RHS being multivariable. But the LHS is clearly a single variable notation.....right?

Comment: @StanShunpike yes, the shorthand  is abuse of notation. When introduced, one should be clear that.

Comment: But how can we abuse it like than and still consider them differentials? Like that just seems like it wouldn't make any sense. Is there a way to write it that doesn't involve this abuse of notation?

Answer (score 1):

We have the *function*

$$ U = U(x,y)$$

from which we create the *equation*

$$x^*,y^*:  U(x^*,y^*) = \bar U$$

with $\bar U$ being fixed a constant, and so $d\bar U = 0$.

Then

$$dU(x^*,y^*) = d\bar U = 0 \implies U_x(x^*,y^*)dx^*+U_y(x^*,y^*)dy^* = 0$$

$$\implies \frac {dy^*}{dx^*} = -\frac {U_x(x^*,y^*)}{U_y(x^*,y^*)}$$

Leaving aside the (mathematical) "Civil War of differentials", there is no abuse of notation here, only simplification for reasons of compactness. Why? $x^*$ and $y^*$ are *solutions to the equation*, not variables free to vary independently.So in reality we have $y^* = h(x^*,\bar U)$ and

$$\implies \frac {dh(x^*,\bar U)}{dx^*} = -\frac {U_x(x^*,h(x^*,\bar U))}{U_y(x^*,h(x^*,\bar U))}$$

**NOTE:** these kinds of notation simplifications appear in all disciplines that use mathematics. They are not always beneficial though: for example M. Caputo in [Foundations of Dynamic Economic Analysis](https://books.google.gr/books?id=XZ2yYSVKWJkC&pg=PA582&lpg=PA582&dq=Caputo%20dynamic%20optimization%20book&source=bl&ots=FpgQhEcvm0&sig=8l4D_Ln0ESLzY9MeIoiZytaOcLE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QQdrVbfuFMelsgGvlYP4Bw&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=Caputo%20dynamic%20optimization%20book&f=false) more than most writes explicitly all dependencies. This makes notation cumbersome and confusing at first, but once you get the hang of it, you are never lost.